# Is lsof part of default RHEL installation?

Tags: rhel, lsof

I am trying to find out if `lsof` is part of a typical RHEL installation. I see `lsof` mentioned in a RHEL page titled [Common administrative commands in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5, 6, 7, and 8](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1189123) but I do not know enough about Linux administration to know whether this means it will always be there or that it may need to be installed.

I am trying to find this out so I can decide if I need to advise uses to install it, or if they (and my script) can assume it will be there.

On a related note, how do I find out everything that a distro would have?

Comment: how about RHEL 9? can't install lsof with `yum install lsof`, get error `Error: Unable to find a match: lsof`

Answer (score 1):

Your script probably needs to run as root to take full advantage of `lsof`.
In that case, this would suffice:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

which lsof  > /dev/null || (echo Installing lsof. && yum install lsof)
```

It's probably enough for your documentation to mention that `lsof` will be installed if missing.

> how do I find out everything that a distro would have?

`$ yum list`, in a VM that you installed with just the defaults.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I want to know contents of a distro _without_ having to install it.

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear to be installed by default.  On a new installation of RHEL 7 I ran

```
yum list | grep lsof
lsof.x86_64                         4.87-6.el7           rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms

yum list installed | grep lsof
<nothing returned>
```

This might be important to know with installations for some versions of Solr for example.  You can install it with

```
yum install lsof
```